# 2.79 Crash on Render (Except Viewport)

Tags: rendering

I just upgraded to 2.79, very excited about the new features (specially the Principled BSDF) but every time I press render image or render animation, it just closes. If I run blender from the command prompt, I can see the error

```
RNA_pointer_get: SceneRenderLayer.cycles not found.
Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

Google turned up a couple dead threads, and nothing changed when I tried what was suggested.

I tried just making a new file, empty scene with just a camera, press render image and it closes. Same thing happens if I expand the preview pannel on a material. Strangely enough, viewport render still works.

PS: Is GPU support seriously gone? So far, 2.79 seems like a downgrade.

Comment: Make sure your system specs match the requirements for Blender 2.79. Also no, GPU support is not gone.

Comment: Make sure your preferences are set properly, and that you are using cycles. If necessary, download the installer/package and unpack/install Blender again and see if it works.

Comment: @VRM That did the trick :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the "Repair" option with a fresh download of the installer from blender.org did the trick. Also fixed GPU rendering abilities